# Surjective map from polynomial ring over a field to the field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $z\in R$ be fixed then the map $\phi:R[x]\rightarrow R $ defined as $\phi(f(x))=f(z)$ is surjective? Could someone please explain me why it is.

Comment: What if instead of $R$ there is $C$?

Comment: The proofs given by Math Gens, egreg, Clive make no assumption about the field / wirk with any field (in fact, with any ring)

Comment: Link to OP's [generalization](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/322365/23500), where $\phi:R[x]\rightarrow C.\ \ $

Answer (score 5):

Let $r \in R$; where does $\phi$ send the polynomial $f$ given by $f(x)=x+r-z$?

[**Edit**] Or, far more simply, consider $f(x)=r$, as egreg points out in the comments.

Comment: Or the constant polynomial $f(x)=r$.

Comment: Ha! I never see the simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** $\,\ \phi\ $ restricts to the identity map on $\rm\,R,\:$ i.e. constants evaluate to themselves.